# Viewing tables ending with dollars ($) in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT table_name, 
               ROWNUM rnum 
          FROM (SELECT table_name 
                  FROM dba_tables
                ) 
         WHERE ROWNUM<=100
       ) 
  WHERE rnum >= 51
```

to return the names of all the tables in my Oracle database.

A number of tables end with the `$` sign, i.e `COLLECTION$`. I've tried using commands like `describe "COLLECTION"`, `describe "COLLECTION$"`, etc. But they don't work. Same with

```
SELECT * 
  FROM COLLECTION
```

and

```
SELECT * 
  FROM COLLECTION$
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the message that the table does not exist

How can I view what is in this table?

Comment: I found theory that tables with dollar sign in the end is data dictionary used for internal purposes, I am not sure is that true. You can select from them, you just do not have privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try prefixing the name of the table with the schema name.

For example

```
desc sys.collection$
```

Here are some notes on object names from the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Notice in particular the "Oracle [strongly] discourages ..." parts.

Comment: Interesting, it said that the tablespace was "SYSTEM", but you need to access it using `sys`?

Comment: I was just guessing -- use of sys was really intended to be an example. If that works then possibly there's a synonym belonging to sys. By the way, never change any tables owned by sys or system.